# Java independent number variable for each object

Tags: java

New to Java, sorry if it's a dumb question. But let's say I have an egg class, and then two subclasses which are brown egg and purple egg. I wanna give them a number starting at 0 and increasing by one each time a new egg object is made, but i'm struggling to find out how.

Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a **static** variable, that is to say a variable shared by all instances of a given class, so that variable can be accessed by all instances( including its Child class instances). Read up on static variables in java.

```
public class Egg {
  static int numberOfEggs=0;

  public Egg(){
    numberOfEggs++;
  }
}
```

Note this code is not thread-safe, but you don't need to worry about that now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a variable that is declared as `static`. Doing so, it will be shared between all instances of your class. Put it in your base class so it will be inherited by the subclasses and increment it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static variable and increment it in the constructor.

```
    class Test
    {
        static int x = 0;

        Test() 
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
```